# How to use global OT variable with Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, opentok

I'm using [OpenTok.js](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/) in an Ionic 4 app.

I included the opentok.js scrpt in the index.html file:

```
<script src="https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.min.js"></script>
```

When I run ionic serve:

- the app works fine
- console.log(OT) prints out the OT global var

When I use ionic cordova run I get:

- an error: error TS2304: Cannot find name 'OT'.

I also considered using the [npm version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@opentok/client).

How could I solve the error ?

Here is the simplified .ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {

  constructor(public platform: Platform) {}

    apiKey:any  = 'XXX';
    sessionId:any = 'XXX';
    token:any = 'XXX';

    ngOnInit(){
       console.log(OT);
       this.initializeSession();
    }

    handleError(error) {}

    initializeSession() {
      var session = OT.initSession(this.apiKey, this.sessionId);

      session.on('streamCreated', function streamCreated(event) {
        var subscriberOptions = {};
        session.subscribe(event.stream, 'subscriber', subscriberOptions, this.handleError);
      });

      session.on('sessionDisconnected', function sessionDisconnected(event) {});

      var publisherOptions = {};
      var publisher = OT.initPublisher('publisher', publisherOptions, this.handleError);

      session.connect(this.token, function callback(error) {
        if (error) {
          this.handleError(error);
        } else {
          session.publish(publisher, this.handleError);
        }
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: where and how are you declaring OT var?

Comment: Try adding `declare let OT:any;` before your component declaration

Comment: Thanks @David ! "Using declare let OT:any;" works